# System of Equations from KhanAcademy

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I watched a video on KhanAcademy explaining about System of Equations and I can't explain why it works.

$W + B = 35 \Longrightarrow$ Equation $A$: measures the distance walk in kilometers.

$\frac{W}{5} + \frac{B}{60} = 1.5 \text{ hours} \Longrightarrow$ Equation $B$: measures the time taken to travel the distance.

*Why are we subtracting the $A$ from $B$?*
They are measuring different units, i.e Distance vs Time.

*Can anyone further explain this?*

Comment: Mathematicians don't usually worry about units.  They just worry about whether the two things can be added in some consistent way.  Two real numbers can always be added in a consistent way.  But if you *are* still worried about the units, then just attach units of km / hour to the $-5$ that is being multiplied by the second equation before adding the equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not to think of equation $A$ as $$W+B=35\text{ km}$$
where $W=r\text{ km}$ and $B=s\text{ km}$, but instead think of it as
$$W\text{ km} + B\text{ km}= 35 \text{ km}$$
$$(W+B)\text{ km}= 35 \text{ km}$$
We have km on both sides of the equation, which after "canceling", leaves us with the unit-less (or dimensionless) pure numerical relationship.
$$W+B=35$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the first equation, the units that appear there are units of distance, as in the problem statement says that the distance between home and school is 35 kilometers. Regarding the second equation, provided that $$v=\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t},$$ where $v$ is the velocity, $\Delta s$ is the distance traveled and the time is $\Delta t$, we have the term $\displaystyle\frac{W}{5}$ measures the time it went and the other end also.

Thus, multiplying $\displaystyle\frac{W}{5}+\frac{B}{60}=1.5$ by $-5$, we have the equation given by $-W-\displaystyle\frac{B}{12}=-7.5$, as the unit has only distance measures. Thus one can add the W equations and to obtain the desired result.

I hope this helps.

Best regards.